# ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value django ajax

Tags: django, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to show the dropdown list with data response via Ajax call. Everything is working fine but I am getting this `ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value` error.

**view:**

```
def load_brand(request):
     if request.is_ajax():
         term = request.GET.get('term')
         brand = Brand.objects.all().filter(brand__icontains=term)

     return JsonResponse(list(brand.values()), safe=False)
```

**ajax:**

```
  $('#id_brand').select2({
      ajax: {
          url: '/brand/ajax/load-brand/',
          dataType: 'json',
          processResults: function (data) {
              return {
                  results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                      return {id: item.id, text: item.brand};
                  })
              };
          }
      },
      minimumInputLength: 1
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ajax call you have not send the `data` i.e : which user type inside select2 and you are accessing them i.e : `request.GET.get('term')` which is empty so your `.filter(brand__icontains=term)` giving you error because `term` value is null.

Instead you can add below as well in your ***ajax call*** :

```
 $('#id_brand').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: '/brand/ajax/load-brand/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(params) {
      var query = {
        term: params.term, //this will be paass
        type: 'public' //optional..
      }
      // Query parameters will be ?term=[values]&type=public
      return query;
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            id: item.id,
            text: item.brand
          };
        })
      };
    }
  },
  minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Also , at your server end you can check if the `term` has any value i.e :

```
 if term:
     brand = Brand.objects.all().filter(brand__icontains=term)
```

For more information check [this](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax)